# Python - Change working directory in subprocess.call syntax

Tags: python, flask, subprocess

I've got some Python code that needs to call an .sh script that lives in a different directory and pass a couple variables to it. It's in a .py file that's part of a Flask path for an API.

```
subprocess.call(shlex.split('script_name.sh {} {}'.format(var1,var2)))
```

It works if I copy the code to a separate .py file and run it directly from a venv when I'm in the directory where the .py file lives AND I include an os.chdir line in that file:

```
os.chdir('/path/to/sh_script_dir')
```

OR if I cd into the directory where the .sh script lives and call it directly using

```
>> python /path/to/py_file.py
```

In the latter case, the os.chdir is not needed. However, when I call it from Flask (by hitting the API path for it, like a "real" user) I get:

```
Exception class: builtins.FileNotFoundError
Exception message: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'script_name.sh'
```

This error happens whether I define the absolute path to the script in that line or not.

I think it's because it's ultimatley being called from the main Flask api.py, which is in whatever working directory it's in, and it's ignoring the os.chdir command.

I know there's another way to do this, with "cwd" but I couldn't get it to work. I've tried many variations on the following but nothing works:

```
subprocess.call(shlex.split('script_name.sh {} {}'.format(var1,var2), cwd = '/path/to/sh_script_dir'))

subprocess.call(shlex.split('script_name.sh {} {}'.format(var1,var2)), cwd = '/path/to/sh_script_dir')

subprocess.call([shlex.split('script_name.sh {} {}'.format(var1,var2))], cwd = '/path/to/sh_script_dir')

subprocess.call([shlex.split('script_name.sh {} {}'.format(var1,var2)], cwd = '/path/to/sh_script_dir'))
```

Do I need to define the change in working dir one level up, in the Flask route?  Side note is that I'm not entirely sure the shlex.split is needed here but it didn't work without it, then it did, so I left it. I can provide more code/info but the problem seems to be very specific to getting this function to run as if the current working directory is where the .sh script lives, not the .py script.

Comment: have you tried: `subprocess.call(['./script_name.sh',var1,var2], cwd = '/path/to/sh_script_dir'))`

Comment: 1) specify current dir (current dir sometimes not in path) and 2) don't use shlex, just pass the args in a list

Comment: what about to call a script with full path? `subprocess.call(shlex.split('path/to/script/script_name.sh {} {}'.format(var1,var2)))` If your script needs something from the directory where it has been run, you can cd in to directory first and then call a script: `subprocess.call(shlex.split('cd path/to/script && script_name.sh {} {}'.format(var1,var2)))`

Comment: @rth that would require `shell=True`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre agree. All OP scripts will require `Shell=True`, I guess.

Comment: @rth: on Linux/Unix it doesnt.

Comment: I tried: `subprocess.call(['./script_name.sh',var1,var2], cwd = '/path/to/sh_script_dir')` and strangely it no longer throws the error when I invoke it from the API endpoint, but it doesn't complete the task the .sh script is supposed to do. Works perfectly if I call it directly. Also, there's an extra `)` at the end of your answer, just in case anyone finds this helpful later.

Comment: As a note, was trying to avoid `Shell=True` since my expectation is I can't always trust the input 100% here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm suspecting that if the `./` isn't passed to `subprocess`, on some systems the command may not be found (security issues, `.` not in system path)

The other issue could be a wrong directory/command not really in the directory.

Obviously I couldn't test that, but that's a safe way (and with error checking) to execute a command in a directory, so it should fix your issue, or at least pinpoint a path problem:

```
command_dir = '/path/to/sh_script_dir'
command_file = os.path.join(command_dir,"script_name.sh")
if not os.path.isfile(command_file):
    raise Exception("{}: no such file".format(command_file))

subprocess.call([command_file,var1,var2], cwd = command_dir)
```

- compose your command file with the full path (stored in a variable)
- test this full path existence prior to running your command (helps to track down a path error)
- don't use `shlex.split` when you can pass the list of arguments instead

Comment: OK awesome, I'm going to work through this and report back, thank you for taking the time! As far as system this is Python 3.6 on Ubuntu 16.04 server, if it matters.

Comment: reading your comments, I doubt that it'll work... but one can try. Maybe a variant: `subprocess.call(["sh","-c",command_file,var1,var2], cwd = command_dir)` (but I think it's equivalent to `shell=True`, maybe a tad safer)